# Change of Coordinates and property of invertible matrices (Sec 2.4 Theorem 8, Hoffman Kunze, Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I was reading Linear Algebra by Hoffman Kunze, and encountered this in the Theorem 8 of the Chapter Coordinates, the theorem is stated below :

[image: coo]

What I get about is in the most bottom line (uniqueness), it says

$"... it\: is\: clear\: that $

$$ \alpha'_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} P_{ij}\alpha_{i}." \tag{a}$$

Is there any easy way to see why it is clear? I tried many ways and what I found was that we start from scratch, (starting the same with the proof, with $\scr \overline{B}$ and then we find an invertible matrix, say $Q$, which we don't know equal to $P$ or not, such that the property (a) above holds with $Q_{ij}$ instead of $P_{ij}$. Then now what we are left to show is that $P$ = $Q$, and we currently have:

$$ x_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} P_{ij} x'_{j}\tag{from (i)}$$

and,

$$ x_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} Q_{ij} x'_{j}$$

So together,

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n} Q_{ij} x'_{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} P_{ij} x'_{j}$$

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n} (Q_{ij} - P_{ij}) x'_{j}= 0$$

The way I showed that this implies that $P$ = $Q$ is by asserting that $P - Q \neq 0^{n\times n}$ and find a contradiction. Suppose $A := P - Q \neq 0^{n\times n}$ then we can choose a row $r$ such that the k-th entry is non-zero, we can plug in $0$ to any other entries other then the k-th and we are left with something non zero equals to $0$ which is a contradiction, so that $A = 0^{n\times n}$ and $P = Q$, and since $(a)$ holds for $Q$ and $P = Q$, it follows that $(a)$ holds for $P$.

I'm pretty sure that the proof is correct since we can plug in various values to $x'_{1}, ... , x'_{n} \in F$, since $F$ is a field, it sure contains $0$ and $1$, but this proof seems to be lengthy and is not as clear as how it was written to be by Hoffman and Kunze, I think I'm missing something here, and will be very thankful for a good explanation. Thanks!

Comment: We first believe that this theorem is correct, so we assume that $\mathcal B'$ exists. If $\mathcal B'$ exists its elements must suffice equation (a). Therefore, we define a set of vectors using equation (a) and try to prove that this set is a basis. **For the uniqueness of $P$, please see my answer.**

Comment: @YourongZang Yes but what confuses me is why : "If  $\mathcal{B}'$ exists its elements must suffice equation (a)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Representing $\alpha_j'$ in the ordered basis $(\alpha_1',\dots,\alpha_n')$ will just give you the standard basis vector $e_j$ because $\alpha_j' = 0\alpha_1' + \dots + 1\alpha_j' + \dots + 0 \alpha_n'$. Multiplying $P$ by $e_j$ gives you the $j$-th column of $P$. So equation (i) says that

$$ [\alpha_j']_{\mathcal B} = \begin{bmatrix} P_{1,j} \\ \vdots \\ P_{n,j} \end{bmatrix}. $$

By definition of $[\alpha_j']_{\mathcal B}$, this means that
$$ \alpha_j' = P_{1,j}\alpha_1 + \dots + P_{n,j}\alpha_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n P_{i,j} \alpha_i. $$

Comment: Thanks! But do you mind telling how did you come to this explanation?

Comment: @hteica Pretty much what I wrote is how I thought through the problem. I had an extra step at the beginning where I thought "$\mathcal{B}'$ represented in $\mathcal{B}'$ should be the identity matrix." That is: $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1' & \cdots & \alpha_n' \end{bmatrix}_{\mathcal B'} = I_n$ from which the right hand side is just the matrix $P$. Then I thought "ok, let's focus on just one column, that will give us the $j$-th column of $I_n$ (namely $e_j$) and then $Pe_j$ will be the $j$-th column of $P$." Then you need to ask "what does it mean if $[\alpha_j']_{\mathcal B} = (c_i)_{i=1}^n$?"

Comment: And that by definition is the same as $\alpha_j' = \sum c_i\alpha_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer & the explanation as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem 8**: this theorem actually starts with the set $\mathcal B'$ which is supposed to be our aimed basis. Therefore, Kunze says: let's define a set of vectors $\mathcal B'$ where its elements are defined by 
$$\alpha'_j=\sum_{i=1}^n P_{ij}\alpha_i$$ and then prove that $\mathcal{B}'$ is a basis for $V$. So the goal is to produce a set with $P$ and to prove that it is a basis.

---

**Uniqueness**: I believe Kunze's Theorem 7 in this chapter proves that if $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ are two bases for vector space $V$ over $F$, there exists a unique $n\times n$ matrix $P$ which suffices
$$[\alpha]_\mathcal{B}=P[\alpha]_{\mathcal{B}'}$$
and
$$[\alpha]_{\mathcal{B}'}=P[\alpha]^{-1}_{\mathcal{B}}$$
The uniqueness of $P$ could be simply proved by regarding it as a collection of unique scalars. **Since every vector in basis $\mathcal B'$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination of vectors in basis $\mathcal B$, the coefficients are unique in the following picture** (and thus the uniqueness of $P$ followers immediately):
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, about the uniqueness of the matrix $P$ is already clear to me, but what still confuses me is that Hoffman and Kunze asserted the property $(a)$ (in the question) by saying that it is a clear consequence of $(i)$ (in the theorem). Does this follow from the uniqueness of P?

Comment: If (a) is satisfied, $\mathcal{B}'$ would be the result of linear transformation $P$ on $\mathcal B$. It does not follow from the uniqueness of $P$. It's just basic vectors (in $\mathcal B$) and matrix multiplication.

Comment: @hteica Is that clear to you?

Comment: Yes thanks, but how can we see that if  $\mathcal{B}'$ satisfies (i) then we have (a) ?

Comment: @hteica it's the definition of $\alpha'_j$'s. They are supposed to be linear combinations of $\alpha_i$'s. If $P$ does change $\alpha_i$ to $\alpha_j'$, it obviously consists of the scalars which form $\alpha_j'$'s with $\alpha_i$'s.

Comment: @hteica Trevor Gunn's answer is probably a more detailed answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer